# extract string from req.url.path in VCL Fastly

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, fastly, fastly-vcl

I need help to extract values from string `req.url.path` which looks like this:

```
/a/b/c/d
```

Need to extract `c`, if there is url, like /a, it should return ''.
I tried

```
regsub(req.url.path, "/a/b/", "\5");
```

Tried with replace too.
but it is not effectively working for me. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following might be along the lines of what you require:

```
if (req.url.path ~ "^/a/.+/c") {
  set req.url = regsub(req.url.path, "/c", "") + "?" + req.url.qs;
}
```

It checks if the URL path begins with `/a` and is followed by `/c` (presuming also that there are segments in-between, such as `/b` as per your given example `/a/b/c/d`).

Here is a Fastly Fiddle link for you to play around with the code:
https://fiddle.fastlydemo.net/fiddle/527480ba

So given the input URL path:

```
/a/b/c/d?id=testing
```

It would change to:

```
/a/b/d?id=testing
```

Notice that the `/c` has been extracted from the path.